# update data('id') and get the new one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am doing a quiz builder in javascript (something like "google form"). People can add and remove "multiple choices questions". Each times a question is added, I set a "data-id" attribute on the question input (textarea).
To link multiple choices to the question I dynamically set its name according to the data-id above.
Like this:

[image]

Everything works good except when I delete a question. Let's say I added 3 questions and I decide to delete the second one.
So I update the data-id "3" to "2" and I update the name of options.

The problem is the data-id is successfully changed (in the html). But not when I try to get the new one.

Here is my code:

```
/* First initialisation */
initNamesQuestion();
initNamesOptions();
$('.question').on('click', '.removeMCQ', function () {
    $(this).parent('div').remove(); // Delete the question block
    /* Update name and data-id */
    initNamesQuestion();
    initNamesOptions();
});
function initNamesQuestion() {
    var nbQuestions = $('.row.question').length; // count questions
    var arrayQuestions = $('.inputQuestion'); // get array of textarea questions
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayQuestions.length; i++) {
        arrayQuestions[i].name = "questions[" + (nbQuestions) + "][]"; // For each question, we change its name
        arrayQuestions[i].setAttribute('data-id', nbQuestions); // set or update a "data" attribute to link options' names
    }
}
function initNamesOptions() {
    var arrayOptions = $('.fake-radiobutton'); // get array of all options
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayOptions.length; i++) {
        var questionID = $(arrayOptions[i]).closest('.card-body').find('.inputQuestion').data('id'); // Get the data-id of the question above
        $(arrayOptions[i]).attr('name',"options[" + (questionID) + "][]"); // set or update the name attribute of the option
    }
}
```

Here is the result in HTML:

[image: imgur image]

Comment: Use a selector to get the length of visible questions to set the ID of each - alternative you can use the .index() of the container

Comment: Thanks. I did not think to simply use index... It works, but I still don't understand why :)

Comment: the index is the count of each of the same elements in a container. So 5 divs in the same container have index 0,1,2,3,4 and if you remove one in the middle, then the index will re-count